# UIInterfaceOrientation in ios6.0

Tags: user-interface, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, uiinterfaceorientation

I am developing box2d game. My game uiinterfaceOrientation is UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft, it working fine in ios5.1 but ios6.0 i am getting interfaceorientation problem. I know – shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: Deprecated in iOS 6.0. For interfaceOrientation they give like interface orientations are set toUIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom. I don't know how to use this(UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll). I need game in UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft. How to solve this problem can you tell me ..
Thanks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a link to a blog about the new functions.](http://dhilipsiva.blogspot.com/2012/07/ios-6-ui-interface-orientation.html)

For your needs all you need to add is:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft;}
```

That will make it so you are only allowed to run landscape left.

Answer (score 0):

Also you should add `UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft` in `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` and `UIInterfaceOrientation`property in Info.plist.  You can also prevent further autorotation by clearly returning false from `shouldAutorotate` callback.